# 2010 Russian Census Data in English

Tags: data-request, census, russia

I am doing a research project and would like to access Russian census data from 2010 that is broken down by region but I do not speak Russian. Does anyone know if this data is available in English? The 2010 data is available here in Russian: https://www.gks.ru/free_doc/new_site/perepis2010/croc/perepis_itogi1612.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've only seen this data in Russian, unfortunately.
From 2010, you can find census population data on Wikipedia but it's also in Russian.  The link is [here](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%A4%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8). Note that you can try the English translation of this page by clicking the [English link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_federal_subjects_of_Russia_by_population) under Languages header in the left sidebar.

If you need help with translation of titles of regions, please do not hesitate to contact me.

Comment: Did you mean to say that you've never seen this data *not* in Russian?

Comment: @katherina this has the base population data which is helpful. Is there an English translation of any socio-economic data from the census that you know of also?